# error: invalid conversion from 'my_type*' to 'int' [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++

A execução do meu código retorna este erro escrito no título. Não sei o que fazer para resolver porque, se vocês virem o código, é claro que o tipo do parâmetro é `BlockGraph` e não `int`. Quando eu coloco um valor inteiro no lugar de block, não é retornado nenhum erro.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <iomanip>
    #include <vector>

    #define INF 0x3f3f3f3f
    #define BOUND 99.99

    typedef int Vertex;
    typedef double Weight;

    using namespace std;

    class BlockGraph
    {
        private:
            int qtyVertices;
            vector< vector<Weight> > adjMatrix;

        public:
            BlockGraph( int );
            void addEdge( Vertex, Vertex, Weight );
            void displayGraph();
    };

    BlockGraph::BlockGraph( int qtyVertices )
    {
        this->qtyVertices = qtyVertices;

        adjMatrix.resize( qtyVertices+1 );
        for( int i = 1; i <= qtyVertices; i++ )
            adjMatrix[i].resize( qtyVertices+1, BOUND );
    }

    void BlockGraph::addEdge( Vertex v, Vertex u, Weight w  )
    {
        adjMatrix[u][v] = w;
        adjMatrix[v][u] = w;
    }

    void BlockGraph::displayGraph()
    {
        cout << endl << "       ";

        for( int i = 1; i <= qtyVertices; i++ )
            cout << setw(7) << "u";
        cout << endl << "       ";

        for( int i = 1; i <= qtyVertices; i++ )
            cout << setw(7) << i;
        cout << endl << endl;

        for( int i = 1; i <= qtyVertices; i++ ){
            cout << setw(3) << "v" << setw(3) << i << "|";
            for( int j = 1; j <= qtyVertices; j++ ){
                cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
                if( adjMatrix[i][j] == BOUND )
                    cout << setw(7) << "INF";
                else
                    cout << setw(7) << adjMatrix[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }
                      //it's a inherit!
    class BrainGraph: public BlockGraph
    {
        private:
            int qtyVertices;
            vector< pair<BlockGraph, int> > blocks;
            vector< vector<Weight> > adjMatrix;

        public:
            BrainGraph( int );
            void addBlock( BlockGraph, int );
            BlockGraph* getBlock( Vertex );
    };

    BrainGraph::BrainGraph( int qtyVertices ):BlockGraph( qtyVertices )
    {
            BlockGraph nil(0);
            blocks.push_back( make_pair( nil, 0 ) );;
    }

            // ------------ MÉTODO DA CLASSE CHAMADO --------------
    void BrainGraph::addBlock( BlockGraph block, int sickcells )
    {
        blocks.push_back( make_pair( block, sickcells ) );
    }
            // ------------ MÉTODO DA CLASSE CHAMADO --------------

    BlockGraph* BrainGraph::getBlock( Vertex x )
    {
        return &blocks[x].first;
    }

    int main()
    {
        BrainGraph* brain;
        BlockGraph* block;

        int orderBrain, qtyEdgesBrain;
        int orderBlock, qtyEdgesBlock;
        int sickcells, h;

        Vertex x, y, start, finish;
        Weight w;

        cin >> orderBrain >> qtyEdgesBrain;
        brain = new BrainGraph( orderBrain );

        for( int i = 1; i <= qtyEdgesBrain; i++ ){
            cin >> x >> y >> w;
            brain->addEdge( x, y, w );
        }

        cin >> start >> finish;

        for( int i = 1; i <= orderBrain; i++ ){
            cin >> orderBlock >> qtyEdgesBlock >> sickcells;
            block = new BlockGraph( orderBlock );

            if( sickcells > 0 )
                for( int l = 0; l < sickcells; l++ )
                    cin >> h;

            for( int j = 1; j <= qtyEdgesBlock; j++ ){
                cin >> x >> y >> w;
                block->addEdge( x, y, w );
            }

            // ------------ ERRO NESSA LINHA --------------
            brain->addBlock( block, sickcells );
            // ------------ ERRO NESSA LINHA --------------

            delete[] block;
        }

        brain->displayGraph();

        for( int v = 1; v <= orderBrain; v++ ){
            cout << endl << endl;
            block = brain->getBlock( v );
            block->displayGraph();
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

O IDE também retorna `note:   initializing argument 1 of 'BlockGraph::BlockGraph(int)'|`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Repare na assinatura do método:

```
void BrainGraph::addBlock( BlockGraph block, int sickcells )
```

Espera um `BlockGraph` quando está a passar um `BlockGraph*`:

```
BlockGraph* block;
...
brain->addBlock(block, sickcells );
```

Se quiser manter a assinatura do método tem de trocar a chamada para:

```
brain->addBlock(*block, sickcells );
```

Alternativamente pode alterar o método `addBlock` para receber um `BlockGraph*` como primeiro parâmetro. Veja qual forma atende melhor os seus objetivos.